# CSS Syntax and stuff

Tags: css

So I have googled a bunch with no help.. I've been working with css for a while but have recently been learning little tricks that I never knew existed (nth child for example) And I have commonly seen > and < inside css like ul > li and stuff like that, so I was wondering where I could find like a list or tutorial or anything that went over the little characters you can use in css? or if anyone can explain :p I tried checking a few sites but they would only explain nesting and um i can't remember what to call it but when you do like [input] so I wanted to know like what else you can do and what exactly it does~ thanks c:

oh and any other little tricks anyone knows would be nice to know as well o: I was so annoyed when I found out about the nth child because that would have been useful to know years ago sigh

Comment: Well, you can start here [CSS Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/)

Comment: Try the [official documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/)

Comment: There are so many resources out there. Good one is at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS. Unfortunately this question is not a good fit for SO.

Comment: This is basically a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14413005/tutorials-for-css which was closed for not being constructive.

Comment: http://learncss.tutsplus.com/

Comment: oh, sorry I didn't realize this wouldn't be 'constructive' I thought I was allowed to ask questions if I didn't understand something or in case anyone else wanted to know exactly what all you could do with css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to look into CSS Selectors. The best non-w3 article for reference might be [this Tuts+ one](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize/).

Comment: wow thank you this is exactly what I was looking for c: i wasn't sure what exactly to search for when I was looking for that p:

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors

Good reference there in that link